# Can't see my hibernate.cfg.xml file

Tags: hibernate, maven

I have some problem with Hibernate. I'm using maven and have such project structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFwOu.png

(Sorry, I can't attach it cause of no reputation)

I use this construction:

```
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

But it doesn't work and I get this error:

```
  Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException:... not found
```

Should I add something to my pom file or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

hibernate.cfg.xml should be in src/main/resources. In src, it won't be added to your classpath for runtime.
In the build path configuration to check that the src/main/resources is not excluded from your class path and is indeed a source folder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change your code as follows;

```
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

I have a similar project like yours and the given code sample works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow following steps mentioned below:

1. Just make sure that hibernate.cfg.xml is at the root of the classpath by specifying it under **src/main/resources**, so that it directly comes under **web-inf/classes** after building the Application
2. Dont specify any absolute path for **hibernate.cfg.xml** file
3. Please add following lines to get SessionFactory

   ```
   Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
   ServiceRegistryBuilder registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
   registry.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
   ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = registry.buildServiceRegistry();
   SessionFactory sessionFactory =     configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
   Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
   ```

Comment: After second step the problem is gone, thank you so much!